# Pytorch nn.Linear different output for same input

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, perceptron

For learning purposes, I'm trying to build a simple perceptron with pytorch which should not be trained but just give the output for set weights. Here's the code:

```
import torch.nn
from torch import tensor

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(3,1)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        # force weights to equal one
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.fc1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones_like(self.fc1.weight))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        output = self.relu(x)
        return output

net = Net()
test_tensor = tensor([1, 1, 1])
print(net(test_tensor.float()).item())
```

I expect this single layer neural network to output 3. And that is **roughly**(!) the output for every execution, but it ranges from 2.5 to 3.5. Where does randomness enter the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Where does randomness enter the model?

It comes from the `bias` init. As you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/394f60b0fcd834bd2613a482b28408f275c0022b/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L93-L96), the `bias` is not initialized to zero as you expected.

You can fix it this way:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(3,1)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        # force weights to equal one
        with torch.no_grad():
            torch.nn.init.ones_(self.fc1.weight)
            torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.fc1.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        output = self.relu(x)
        return output

x = torch.tensor([1., 1., 1.])
Net()(x)
# >>> tensor([3.], grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)
```